# A tiny ajax ping to prevent session timeout?

Tags: http, session, timeout

On my website, members can write articles to share info with others in their community. I get random reports that the submit fails, and it appears it is because of session timeout.

If I create a small ajax script to "ping" an action on my ASP.NET MVC controller every few minutes, would that reset the session timeout? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

An ajax ping is what I do in my Java EE MVC web application to keep the session alive, and it works fine. I don't see why it should not work for a ASP.NET application as well.

I am not sure if there is a better way, though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that will do the job.

Independently of the technologies, every time an http request reaches the http server, the session "last access time" is updated to the date the communication has been initiated by the client.

If you ping to the server with a delay less than the session timeout you will preserve the session for ever!

Note: you don't need to ping every minutes if your session time out is 30 minutes. It will overload the network for absolutely nothing. I would recommend the session to ping every 25 minutes for such configuration.

HIH
M.